# Pass current url as variable to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry if this has already been answered, but I couldn't find it.

I'm trying to select the link with the current url as it's href in a ul of links, and expand it's parents.

Html:

```
<ul class ='product-categories'>
     <li><a href ='http://example.com/link1'>Link 1</a>
           <ul>
                 <li><a href ='http://example.com/link/sub-link1'>Sub link 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href ='http://example.com/link/sub-link2'>Sub link 2</a></li>
                 <li><a href ='http://example.com/link/sub-link3'>Sub link 3</a></li>
           </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href ='http://example.com/link2'>Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href ='http://example.com/link3'>Link 3</a></li>
     <li><a href ='http://example.com/link4'>Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
var url = document.URL;
$('a[ href = url ]').parentsUntil('ul.product_categories').slideToggle('fast');
```

For some reason this works if I paste the url directly into the function, but doesn't work with a variable?  I've tried using window.location.href instead, same result.  Have also alerted the contents of url, which was fine.

Concatenating it into the function has the same result.

Doesn't work:

```
$('a[href= " + url + "]').parentsUntil('ul.product_categories').slideToggle('fast');
```

If I paste the url directly into the function, it works

```
$('a[href= "http://example.com/product-category/bamboo-cutting-board/round-cutting-board/"]').parentsUntil('ul.product_categories').slideToggle('fast');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String concatenation:

```
$('a[href="' + url + '"]')
```

Comment: That came up with a syntax error.  If if do $('a[href= " + url + "]'), I get the same result as $('a[ href = url ]'), which is nothing.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href=http://imw1248.info/product-category/bamboo-cutting-board/round-cutting-board/]

Comment: Are you missing a beginning quote?

Comment: Yes, just realised i need to concatenate like this  $('a[href= "' + url + '"]') If you change your syntax I"ll mark as correct